# Options after opening a phishing website on my android

Tags: antivirus

Someone sent me a link in WhatsApp claiming I can get a chance to get two free Emirates plane tickets, at first I just thought of it as a hoax but I was curious at the same time so I opened the link and followed its instructions to share the page with 20 people and answered a few questions. Yes I was stupid. My question is what can one do after visiting a phishing website on Android?  Like scan the phone for virus? I didnt find anything strange installed on my phone...

Comment: That's not a phishing site I guess. And, it will not affect you in anyway, since that's just a spam page (unless you entered your credentials ofcourse). And there is no way it can install a virus like you suppose. So just move on..

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache, as first step and if you want to be doubly sure run a malware detection app from Play store. [Malware bytes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware) is a good idea since it gives you pro features free for one month

It may or may not be a phishing site but since you are rightly concerned, this should be enough.